# Как вызвать функцию из функции, которая в классе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

```
class D:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Ivan"

    def test(self):
        print(self.name)

        def test1(self):
            print(self.name)  # не работает

        test1()

launch = D()
launch.test()
```

Answer (score 3):

Нужно различать функции и методы:

```
launch.test()  # Вызов метода
test1()        # Вызов функции
```

У методов по умолчанию задается параметр `self`, который незаметно перекладывается при вызове метода объектом:

```
# В test будет передана ссылка на launch, т.е. self это launch
launch.test()
```

Поэтому, для функции `test1` нужно вручную передавать параметр, раз его объявили:

```
    def test1(self):
        print(self.name)

    test1(self)
```

Либо, не указывайте в `test1` ничего и обращайтесь к `self`, т.к. область действия происходит внутри метода и `self` будет доступен:

```
    def test1():
        print(self.name)

    test1()
```